# How can I allow members to view and edit their own records?

Tags: wordpress, civimember

1. Front-End Interface for End-Users

- Develop a login based front-end portal for members where they can login using individual credentials, and see their own records.
- Front-end GUI will show members static information for their accounts including
  o   Name, address, email, phone, birthday, professional skills, etc.
  o   Add/update family members, relationship, personal info for each family member (name, address, email, phone, birthday, professional skills, etc.)
  o   Membership status (lifetime, annual, date of expiry if annual)
  o   Data of financial pledges, payments made, balances due, donation summary
  o   File attachment section where admins can upload pdf files (for e.g. tax statements, receipts, etc.)
- Email notification when a member makes a change to their account
- Forgot and reset password functions

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! This is a good question that I think will be useful for others. I've edited the title to make it easier for other people to find it. I hope that's okay.

Answer (score 6):

Depends how complicated you want to make it, though we simply use:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/ - to restrict content to members
- https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-wordpress-member-sync - to set up the WordPress users and keep them in sync so the right people can access the right content
- if you are running CiviCRM on WordPress https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-admin-utilities comes highly recommended by many if you are not already using it

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/wordpress/ explains things pretty well, including frontend dashboard `[civicrm component="user-dashboard"]` and profiles.

- emails on submission is I think a setting in a profile (though you could also use Caldera Forms (or its impending replacement to capture information and I recall that has many more settings for notifications etc - a good place to start would be https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf-civicrm-formprocessor/
- Forgot and reset password functions - using the above approach with Members and Members Sync etc allow you to just use the WordPress default system for login, forget and reset functions etc (and there a many a WordPress plugin to style and tweak the WordPress login page.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, I will follow your instructions....